# php проверка выполнения запроса с внешнего ресурса (openweathermap)

Tags: php, openweathermap

Если неудачный запрос с внешнего источника, вот такая ошибка:

Warning: file_get_contents(...): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in D:\phpProject\1Server\www\map.php on line 43

Получая я используя:
$getdataOpenWeather = file_get_contents($urlOpenWeather);

Как собственно проверить, если запрос неудачный, чтобы я смог вывести сообщение, а не такую ошибку)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как частичное решение - использовать "@" - @file_get_contents(..) для подавления сообщения и проверять размер ответа, чтобы он был больше нуля.

Можно попробовать вот такой совет

```
function custom_file_get_contents($url) {
return file_get_contents(
    $url,
    false,
    stream_context_create(
        array(
            'http' => array(
                'ignore_errors' => true
            )
        )
    )
);
}

$content=FALSE;

if($content=custom_file_get_contents($url)) {
    //play with the result
} else {
    //handle the error
}
```